# cannot authenticate by Google Client API Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-client-login

I’m trying the Android app using Firebase.
I need to authenticate by Google Client API in order to use Firebase.
But, I can’t authenticate by Google Client API.

In following code, `GoogleSignInResult.isSuccess()` returns false.
`GoogleSignInResult.getState().getStateMessage()` returns null. So, I don’t know why Google authentication failed.

Is there something you have to do when using Google authentication?
Thanks in advance.

Note:
I can authenticate by Google Client API when I install release.apk by the command “add install release.apk”.
But I cannot authenticate when I install via Google Play Store( not BETA but RELEASE).

Screenshot:
After login button pressed(login button:lower right button)
[image]

Code:
In onActivityResult, `GoogleSignInResult.isSuccess()` returns false.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    public static GoogleApiClient googleAPIClient;

    private DatabaseReference usersRef;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener onConnectionFailedListener = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onCreate - start");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        try {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

            GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            googleAPIClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, onConnectionFailedListener)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
                    .build();

            firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onCreate - start");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        System.out.println("LoginActivity.onStop - start");
        if (null != usersRef) {
            usersRef.removeEventListener(valueEventlistener);
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void onCancelButtonClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }

    public void onLoginButtonClick(View view) {
        System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onLoginButtonClick - start");
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleAPIClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);
        System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onLoginButtonClick - end");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onActivityResult - start");

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN) {
            System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onActivityResult - in if");
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onActivityResult - in if success");
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onActivityResult - in if error");
                System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onActivityResult - in if error state:" + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error:" + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("*** LoginActivity.onActivityResult - end");
    }

    public void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        // firebase authentication
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added your Release version SHA1 Fingerprint in the Firebase Project Setting?

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't know that the SHA1 of the apk generated by "Generate Signed APK" is different  from one of released apk on Google Play Store at all.Thank you so much!

Comment: I should have read the following article.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423